# Python Open CV2 Color Detection Mask to Pixel Coordinates

Tags: python, opencv, coordinates, mask

I am currently working in Python to do color detection on a single image. After loading my image and establishing my RGB (or BGR in CV2), I use the following 2 lines to produce a mask and a output image.

```
mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower, upper)
output = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask = mask)
```

Then the code displays the following image.

[image: Output of my color detection]

But now, I would like to take the processed image and extract pixel coordinate points for the green line.

Thanks. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So to be clear, you have the image you posted and you want coordinates of the pixels in the green line ? (your code snippet is confusing me a little bit, it's not part of the problem is it ?)

Comment: The image you posted is the original image next to the result, right ?

Answer (score 2):

So, how about findNonZeros() on a binarised version of your image ?
Starting with the image with the green line on black background :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread(output.png)
img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) #converting to grayscale
img = img.astype(np.uint8)

#get all non zero values
coord = cv2.findNonZero(img)
```

EDIT : It has been pointed out on another question that you can also use numpy's function nonzeros. It gives the same results, but I find it to be slower

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time 

so=cv2.imread(your_image,0)

start1=time.clock()
coord=cv2.findNonZero(so)
end1=time.clock()

start2=time.clock()
coord2=np.nonzero(so)
end2=time.clock()

print("cv2.findNonZeros() takes "+str(end1-start1)+" seconds.")
print("np.nonzero() takes       "+str(end2-start2)+" seconds.")

>>> cv2.findNonZeros() takes 0.003266 seconds.
>>> np.nonzero() takes       0.021132 seconds.
```