# How do I know the position of white areas detected using OpenCV in python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

For example in this code i have filtered the video feed to show the white areas. How do i know their position/coordinates?(x,y)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(1):
    _, frame = cap.read()
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    # define range of white color in HSV
    # change it according to your need !
    lower_white = np.array([0,0,0], dtype=np.uint8)
    upper_white = np.array([0,0,255], dtype=np.uint8)

    # Threshold the HSV image to get only white colors
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_white, upper_white)
    # Bitwise-AND mask and original image
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame, mask= mask)
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    cv2.imshow('mask',mask)
    cv2.imshow('res',res)

    k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Have a look at [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41837005/python-open-cv2-color-detection-mask-to-pixel-coordinates/41871937#41871937)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use numpy way of getting all the values in a matrix which are not zero.

```
indcies = numpy.nonzero(res)
```

Comment: what if i have found a single big blob? how can i find its center?

Comment: Take the mean value of the x corrdinates and the mean value of the y corrdinates

Answer (score 0):

Following up on Amitay's answer, you can also use OpenCV's function `findNonZero`. I don't know in what way it is differently implemented than numpy's `nonzero`, but if gives the same results and it is faster (which can be useful for large loops or images)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time 

so=cv2.imread(your_image,0)

start1=time.clock()
coord=cv2.findNonZero(so)
end1=time.clock()

start2=time.clock()
coord2=np.nonzero(so)
end2=time.clock()

print("cv2.findNonZeros() takes "+str(end1-start1)+" seconds.")
print("np.nonzero() takes       "+str(end2-start2)+" seconds.")

>>> cv2.findNonZeros() takes 0.003266 seconds.
>>> np.nonzero() takes       0.021132 seconds.
```