# How to crop area from mask in cv2 python

Tags: python, image, opencv

I have videos of black screen and a white ball
I want to track the centre of the white ball in **every** frame (output as x, y co-ordinate). So my attempt is to use `cv2.HoughCircles` but no matter how I tuned the parameter, I won't get 100% tracking.

So I have another idea. Because when average every pixel of circle shape will get the centre point of the circle. I decided to try on that idea. But looping every pixel until we found the white isn't feasible. Is there any way to crop (roughly) to get only white circle pixel? (For example, I have image resolution of 1920x1080 but the ball's size won't exceed 50x50 pixel. So it would be too slow to process it in python. So is there a way to crop a region in an image to 50x50 in size?)

Comment: By Black and White image, I mean absolute black (0, 0, 0) and white (255, 255, 255)

Comment: From your description, it seems like Hough circles should work. But it could be that your method of looking for white blobs will be faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I've got it.
Here is my solution

```
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower_white = np.array([0,0,150], dtype=np.uint8)
upper_white = np.array([0,0,255], dtype=np.uint8)
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_white, upper_white)

indcies = np.nonzero(mask)
size = len(set(zip(indcies[0], indcies[1])))
avgX, avgY = 0, 0
minX, minY = 10000, 10000
maxX, maxY = -1, -1

for (x, y) in set(zip(indcies[0], indcies[1])):
    minX, minY, maxX, maxY = min(minX, x), min(minY, y), max(maxX, x), max(maxY, y)
    avgX += x
    avgY += y
avgX /= size
avgY /= size
radius = int(round(max(maxX - minX, maxY - minY)/2))
cv2.circle(image,(int(round(avgY)),int(round(avgX))),radius,(0,255,0),2)
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

Reference:

- [How do I know the position of white areas detected using OpenCV in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41919319/how-do-i-know-the-position-of-white-areas-detected-using-opencv-in-python)

Comment: Noted: The cropped area is (minX, minY) to (maxX, maxY)